# How to hide the bottom navigation bar in certain fragments?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack, android-bottomappbar, android-jetpack-navigation

I have An activity with a navGraph and a bottom Navigation bar with 2 menu items.
My problem is that My Bottom Navigation Bar appears everywhere, detailFragment, aboutFragment, signInFragment and so on.

```
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)

        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.contactsFragment,
            R.id.profileFragment
        ).build()

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController)
```

How do i Limit it to just show on the 2 fragments on my menu Item?

**This is how I solved It**

```
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener{ _, nd: NavDestination, _->
        if(nd.id == R.id.contactsFragment || nd.id == R.id.profileFragment){
            navView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }else{
            navView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for editing in the solution, saved me some time!

Comment: You're welcome @SlowDeep , Happy Coding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your fragment where it should be visible

```
navView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Where it shouldn't be visible

```
navView.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: Worked, Thanks, the biggest problem was finding the fragments to set the visibility, ended up using a listener

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to hide bottom navigation view from your current fragment, that is in main activity or parent activity. Well it's that easy. Just go to the fragment where you don't want bottom navigation view and paste the following code bellow onCreateView.

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val view = requireActivity().findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)

    val fab = requireActivity().findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab)
    view.visibility = View.GONE
    fab.visibility = View.GONE
}
```